# Open Web Studio - How to use in skin file in DNN Website

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

My DNN Website uses lots of ListX controls.

I have successfully upgraded the listX controls to OWS.

However I am not sure how can I use it in Skin files

Following is a ListX tag.

```
<b4:LISTX runat="server" id="lxNavigator" TabID="114" ModuleID="457" TabModuleID="158" useCurrent="False" />
```

I need to update this code with OWS equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

If you have upgraded ListX to OWS and have to embed the control in Skin Objects you need to do the following changes in the Skin files of DNN.

Register the control

```html
<%@ Register Assembly="r2i.OWS.Wrapper.DotNetNuke" Namespace="r2i.OWS.Wrapper.DNN" TagPrefix="OWS" %>
```

Place the following tag where you want to render the OWS control

```html
<OWS:SkinObject id="OWSNavigator" ConfigurationID="4FEAFFBD-4DB2-455B-9DA9-28251A875D62" runat="server"></OWS:SkinObject>
```

[Here](http://www.openwebstudio.com/topic/How_To_Implement_An_OWS_Module_As_A_Skin_Object.aspx) is a reference